# Is there a verb for read out loud?

Tags: word-request

I checked the dictionary and recite implies you've memorized the novel or work, and narrated implied you're telling a story instead of reading out loud. Is there a true synonym of "reading out loud" as in "he read out his novel out loud while holding the novel with his palms"?

Comment: **To read aloud** is the phrase commonly used when the reading is intended for an audience.

Comment: You hold a book _in your hands_ - 'with his palms' is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any single word that isn't context-specific but, like Ronald Sole in his comment, I would be more likely to use "aloud" instead of "out loud" (both are acceptable).